# Replacing the "Page Not Available" WebView element with a custom one. java android

Tags: java, android

I am new to java. Strongly do not scold me dear programmers! I have an android application running on a WebView. I need to replace the "Page not available" display with the template, element I need. For this I used webView.loadUrl. But unfortunately all to no avail. I am attaching the code. What will be the advice? Thanks to all.

What am I doing wrong?

```
enter code here
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        final Activity activity = this;

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://ya.ru/") || url.startsWith("https://ya.ru/"))) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://play.google.com/") || url.startsWith("https://play.google.com/"))){
                        view.getContext().startActivity(
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                    }
                 else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("src/main/res/index1.html");
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //webView.loadUrl("src/main/res/error_page/index1.html");
                try {
                    view.stopLoading();
                }
                catch(Exception e){}
                view.clearView();
            }
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }

        });

        webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                    switch(keyCode)
                    {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                            if(webView.canGoBack())
                            {
                                webView.goBack();
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

 webView.loadUrl("https://saluut.ru/");
        setContentView(webView);
    }
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

you might try putting *index1.html* in the [assets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#OriginalFiles) directory of your Android project and then you can try accessing that file like so:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index1.html");
```

The following answer shows the detailed steps: [Where and how to put HTML files in Android app resource files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377444/where-and-how-to-put-html-files-in-android-app-resource-files)

Comment: still showing the WebView element "Page not available"(

Comment: Do you see that the the HTML assets are being included in the _build/assets_ directory of your project?